# Component does not render

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks, react-state

blog.js execution starts from this if we click the posts link.

I am calling the history.push in posts.js twice, but the new-post is not rendering, like the console logs specified in newpost.js. ComponentDidMount and the render method are not executing, but it is executing the console log in posts.js.

Blog.js:

```js
class Blog extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div  className="Blog">
               <ul>
                   <li>
                       <Link to="/posts" exact>Posts</Link>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <Link to="/new-post">New Post</Link>
                   </li>
                            
               </ul>
               <Switch>
                   <Route path="/new-post" render={()=>(<Newpost/>)}/>
                   <Route path="/posts" component={Posts}/>
                   <Route path="/" exact component={Posts}/>
                   <Route render={()=><h1>Not Found</h1>}/>
               </Switch>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Posts.js  (rendered when we call posts link in blog.js):

```js
class Posts extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
            console.log("render");
        });
    }

    postselect = (id) => {
            this.props.history.push('/new-post');
            console.log("hello");
            console.log("hello");
            console.log("hello");
            console.log("hello");
            
            this.props.history.push('/posts');
    }
    render()
    {
        console.log("posts render");
        return(
            <div>
            <button onClick={this.postselect}>submit</button>
            </div>);
    }
}
```

newposts.js (should render if we call this route):

```js
class NewPost extends Component {

    componentDidMount(){
        console.log("hellonewpost");
    }
    
    render () {
        console.log("newpost render");
        return (
            <div className="NewPost">
                ...
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: <button onClick={()=>this.postselect()}>submit</button>  try with this.

Comment: same thing happened...no change

Comment: maybe because you use Link element outside of switch ?

Comment: wrap <div  className="Blog"> with Router component and try one more time

Answer (score 0):

You can't post push history twice in the same function. I'm not too sure what you are trying to do, but I'm assuming you want to do something like this:

```
 postselect =(id)=>
    {
            this.props.history.push('/new-post');
    }
```

In your New-Post component:

```
componentDidMount{
 console.log("hello");
 console.log("hello");
 console.log("hello");
 console.log("hello");
 this.props.history.push('/posts');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing 2 `history.push`es concurrently in one function.

**Note that** - the javascript engine will do the history.push once your click handler function is finished its execution. By the time the function execution finishes the history object is modified(2nd time) to have `/posts` and therefore `/new-post` is never rendered

In general it is a best practice to have `history.push` as a last line of code in a function.

**EDIT**(based on comment)

Here is [a demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/history-push-issue-fix-18umg?file=/src/Home.js) . Go to `Home.js` and click the button and observe the console.logs.

Comment: what happens if i keep a push('/new-post') in posts.js and then some console log ...instead of 2 push .... then it is navigating to new-post' and then console log is outputting....      But you said that the JavaScript engine will do history.push after execution of whole function...???

Comment: yes... in your function, if you do history.push followed by console.log, then console.log is printed first and then (after finishing function execution), the routing is done... i have updated the answer with a demo...so check the console.logs there.